# Why can you use an LED below voltage?

Tags: led, physics, joule-thief

If you put too little voltage across an LED, nothing happens, as I would expect.  However, I've seen a demo where a red LED is powered with a 1.5V cell, and it lights.  I assumee that red LEDs are 1.9v or so, and was wondering whether there is a range in which they can glow a little bit, and if so, what accounts for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm betting what you saw was a [joule thief](http://www.nifty-stuff.com/led-boost-circuit-joule-thief.php).

However, small amounts of current do flow below the forward voltage (see image) of an LED so perhaps it could very dimly light before hitting Vf.

[image]

Comment: That Joule Thief link wasn't very useful, I found http://www.thejoulethief.com/joule.html (Schematic images [here](http://www.thejoulethief.com/images/sch.bmp) and [here](http://www.joulethief.com/images/boost-schematics.gif), Eagle files also on that page) much more helpful.  There's a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief), but that isn't particularly good.

Comment: @Kevin It was the most applicable one for a 1.5V AA battery I thought... perhaps not the device as a whole

Comment: @Kevin Funny how the kit has two \$2.2k \Omega\$ resistors and one \$1k \Omega\$, but the schematic has the opposite...

Comment: @madmanguruman yeah that seems not ideal

Comment: No, I meant you could see a AA battery wired to an LED, no other circuitry involved, but I like the Joule thief so much I'm giving this answer the credit

Comment: @Kevin `thejoulethief.com` domain seems to be up for sale/squatted. (Dead link)

Comment: Some LEDs do very definitely glow quite noticeably in dim environments at voltages well below Vf; the real "culprit" is the dynamic range of the human eye.  The amount of light required for a glowing object to be visble in a dark room is often well below 1/10,000 of the amount required to be noticeable in bright sunlight, so it doesn't take much current at all to make things glow when they shouldn't.

Answer (score 6):

Some LEDs have a forward voltage of 1.5V or less at reasonable currents.  Look at the datasheet of some red LEDs for example.  The forward voltage will also be lower at higher temperature.

Comment: This is almost certainly what was happening to me, but the Joule thief posting was highly useful!

Answer (score 0):

The reason, that you can use diode below saturation voltage (knee voltage) is that the current value depends on voltage by Shockley diode equation. See [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_modelling#Shockley_diode_model)